# Use regex as input file path in Logstash

Tags: logstash

I would like to parse a directory of logs files with logstash.
When the logs are formatted like this :

```
server-20140604.log
server-20140603.log
server-20140602.log
```

There is no problem, I am using globs like this :

```
input {
 file {
   path=>["D:/*.log"]
 }
}
```

But my logs are formatted like this :

```
server.log
server.log.1
server.log.2
client.log
client.log.1
client.log.2
```

So I would like to know how to tell to logstash to parse in the folder all the files starting with "server" expression in their names. I really need to do it like that, because I have other files in the folder (i.e client logs) that I don't want to parse but also cannot remove from the folder.

Comment: Have you tried server.*?  Pretty sure logstash uses the unix globbing conventions, not the windows one, but I could be wrong

Comment: I just tried. With server.*. It takes server.log.1 and server.log.2 but not server.log. But what it's very strange, it's that while I let the agent running, I open server.log with notepad, and then do "save as" with new encoding utf-8 (old was ANSI) and then replace the old file, at this moment the file is automatically detected by logstash. I know the immediate detection because I have a kibana running also which shows me in reel time what logstash parses and sends to elasticsearch.

Comment: not `server.*.`, just `server.*` or possibly `server.**`

Comment: Yes, I did like you have said, i.e "server.*" The second dot wat to mark the end of my sentence.

Answer (score 1):

With this configuration I can only parse all the log files start with prefix `server`.

```
input {
        file {
                path => ["D:/server*"]
        }
}

output {
    stdout {
                codec => rubydebug
        }
}
```

I think the possible problem you have meet is the `start_position` config. It means that where does logstash start to read the logs. Please refer to [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.1/inputs/file#start_position). Remember this option only modifies `first contact` situations where a file is new and not seen before. If a file has already been seen before, this option has no effect.

When you stop logstash, logstash will save a .sincedb* in your home directory. Next time you start it, logstash will start read the file according to .sindb*. If you do not input new logs to `server.log`, logstash will never parse the old logs.

What you can try to do is delete all the .sincedb before you start logstash and add `start_posistion` to your config. In your comment you have say if you overwrite the `server.log` logstash can parse the file from beginning, it is because logstash detect it as a new file and the .sincedb* do not save any information about this file. So logstash will parse it! You can try to find out your .sincedb and try to delete it.

Comment: Ok thanks, so I guess I will have to use start_position, but with the doc, I am not seeing the impact of beginning or end, could you please tell me how these 2 values will affect the parsing of a directory with glob input.

Comment: Well, this setting only impact on the file which the file is new and not seen before by logstash. Beginning means logstash will parse the logs from the beginning when it meet new file, and the End means logstash will not parse any logs of the new file and start monitor from the end of the file